# Issue with querying dates with $gte and $lt

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to make searchDate API (I am using Express, Mongoose and Angular).
I need to return list of data between two dates.

Somehow it is working only if I hardcode date in $gte and $lt

My api code:

```
    router.get("/searchDate", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { startDate, endDate } = req.query;

    const containers = await Container.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          $or: [
            {
              manufacturingDate: {
                $gte: new Date(startDate),
                $lt: new Date(endDate),
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    ]);
    res.status(200).json(containers);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json({ success: false, msg: "Container not found" });
  }
});
```

And my model is:

```
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";
const ContainerType = require("./ContainerType");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ContainerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  owner: { type: String, required: true },
  manufacturingNo: { type: String, required: true },
  IdentificationNo: { type: String, required: true },
  manufacturingDate: { type: Date, required: true },
  nextInspectionDate: { type: Date, required: true },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Containers", ContainerSchema);
```

That is how the date looks in my MongoDB Compass
[image]

An error I am getting from the api /searchDate is:
[image]

Comment: _"...data between two dates."_ You need to use the `$and` operator (not the `$or`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with Mongo, and is just a regular TypeScript error.

The `startDate` and `endDate` variables are not (as far as TS can tell) necessarily safe to construct a Date object from.

You can either cast, e.x. `new Date(String(startDate))`, or better, `assert` or `throw` somewhere above if `typeof startDate !== 'string'`.

This is assuming that `startDate` is indeed a string, which is highly likely but not necessarily true (as TypeScript is telling you).

Keep in mind it's also possible that constructing a Date from a string can result in an `Invalid Date` object.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I managed it to work and also did that, if i get Invalid Date, i return empty string and it is working. Thanks